# Hard time installing windows xp on Compaq Pressario SR1520IL.

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation, bios, setup

One day morning I started getting this error on my desktop:

> Reboot and select proper boot device or Insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key.

I checked out all the settings in the BIOS whose specifications are:

AMI BIOS : Version 3.21

The BOOT Priority was correct: First Floppy drive then CD and then Hard Disk.

I saw the list of devices installed: It was showing both floppy and two cd drives but was not able to detect the hard drives - I didn't open up my CPU for looking Hard Disk connections because it was detectable while I tried to fresh install Windows XP from a CD, therefore,  I thought that I will reinstall the Windows XP.

But now the problem is: After copying a list of files to the C Drive, and then restarting the PC, it doesn't show me "Press any key to boot from CD...". So, it always boots from CD, although I have correct settings on BIOS ( I have tried setting default settings also). So everytime after restarting, it again starts copying the initial startup list of files to the Drive and do not proceed further.

This was the third attempt. In the first attempt, it was showing "Press any key to boot from cd...", but if I didn't press any key then it used to come back to the boot screen again and again.

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You told that you have two drives in your systems. So first remove one cd drive and made another cd drive two slave and go to bios and change the boot priority as first boot drive to cd drive and second boot drive to hard disk. now you start to installation of OS in your system.
I hope this will work if not than plz reply.